# Javascript Function does not return expected output

Tags: javascript

I am just a little confused on why I get the output of  [Function] when I am executing a function that I created.

```
var nameString = function (name) {

return "Hi, I am" + " " + name;     
};


nameString("Yasser");
console.log(nameString);
```

I understand that I am using the function within console.log to print out the value of it. Is it not supposed to print out my name "yasser" instead of saying function?

Answer (score 3):

When you do `console.log(nameString)`, it will just print the output of `.toString()` called on that function like `nameString.toString()`. The output of this will be `[Function]`

You need to execute the function `nameString` with string argument and then log the returned output as follows

```
console.log(nameString("Yasser"))
```

Answer (score 1):

Because you are running console.log on the function, you are not calling it, so you wont get the return value. I see you have called the function above the console.log, but you have not assigned the value anywhere

try

```
console.log(nameString("Yasser"));
```

or

```
var s = nameString("Yasser");
console.log(s);
```

Answer (score 1):

You are returning a string from your function but not assigning it to anything.

When you `console.log` you are not using the result of the previous call; you are simply printing what is, in effect in Javascript, a function pointer.

To fix this you should assign the result to a variable:

```
var name = nameString("Yasser");
console.log(name);
```

Or simply inline the result of the function:

```
console.log(nameString("Yasser"));
```

Answer (score 1):

Very basic thing for you to understand in the Javascript code shared, There are two things to be considered:

1. Function Reference ----> **nameString** is the just a reference to the function. Nothing more!

   Check this: 
   http://jsfiddle.net/d73heoL2/1/

```js
var nameString = function (name) {

return "Hi, I am" + " " + name;     
};
alert(typeof nameString);
```

2. Function call----> For a function to execute, you need to call it. For ex:

> nameString();

Having said that, what you wanted can be achieved like this:

```js
var nameString = function (name) {

return "Hi, I am" + " " + name;     
};

alert(nameString('WooCommerce'));
```

Comment: Perfect Explanation! Appreciated @Rakesh_Kumar